# How to fix: "Unable to derive module descriptor for jboss-interceptors-api_1.2"

Tags: java, maven, javafx, cdi, jboss-weld

I am new to Java and I am trying to create a Java SE application using JavaFX 13 for the GUI and Weld for CDI. I created the project following the JavaFX website and the initial project ran fine. When I added Weld and added it to the module-info.java, it gave me the error "Information:java: java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Keyshawn.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar" and I am unsure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Information:java: compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.4, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
Information:java: java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\*\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:647)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readModule(ModulePath.java:330)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scan(ModulePath.java:236)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scanNextEntry(ModulePath.java:189)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.findAll(ModulePath.java:165)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findAll(Resolver.java:842)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.bind(Resolver.java:223)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:482)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:288)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getServiceLoader(JavacFileManager.java:985)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain$2.invoke(JavacMain.java:290)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.initProcessorLoader(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:261)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:237)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:193)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1136)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:922)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:195)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:460)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:330)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:255)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:213)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1324)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1004)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1071)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:965)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:794)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Information:java: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jboss.interceptors.api.1.2.spec: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.Checks.requireModuleName(Checks.java:52)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$Builder.<init>(ModuleDescriptor.java:1550)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.newAutomaticModule(ModuleDescriptor.java:2438)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.deriveModuleDescriptor(ModulePath.java:507)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:643)
Information:java:   ... 49 more
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'javafxcdi'
Information:javac 11.0.4 was used to compile java sources
Information:10/20/2019 1:16 PM - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 756 ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

Here is my JavaFX Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
        final SeContainer container = initializer.initialize();
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.keyshawn</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafxcdi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.keyshawn.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my module-info.java:

```
module com.keyshawn {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires weld.se.core;
    requires cdi.api;
    opens com.keyshawn to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.keyshawn;
}
```

IDE: Intellij

Java Version: 11.0.4

JavaFX Version: 13

Build Tool: Maven

**UPDATE**:

So there was not answers in a duplicate question that specifically answered my question. After doing some digging around, I have changed my POM to add the weld-se-shaded instead of weld-se-core. The dependencies in my pom look like this now

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So that worked, only through Intellij. When run on the command-line with the javafx-maven-plugin, I got a different error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.keyshawn:javafxcdi >-----------------------
[INFO] Building javafxcdi 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) @ javafxcdi ---
[WARNING] Required filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository!
Oct 20, 2019 3:03:03 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 3.1.2 (Final)
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000033: Invalid bean archive scanning result - found multiple results with the same reference: C:\Users\Keyshawn\Documents\Projects\javafx-basic-tutorials\blog-javafx\javafxcdi\target\classes
    at weld.se.shaded@3.1.2.Final/org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
    at weld.se.shaded@3.1.2.Final/org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.createDeployment(Weld.java:955)
    at weld.se.shaded@3.1.2.Final/org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:777)
    at weld.se.shaded@3.1.2.Final/org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:176)
    at com.keyshawn/com.keyshawn.App.start(App.java:23)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.keyshawn.App
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

After doing some messing around with it and some research, this is what I got to work with both the IDE and the command-line, at least for now with my current code.

```
package com.keyshawn;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        final SeContainer container = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance()
                .addPackages(true, App.class)
                .disableDiscovery()
                .initialize();
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

I do not know why I have to disable bean discovery, I thought that it should just work out the box with my previous code. I am curious to know why that is.